# Triangle and parametric coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

I'm studying on a book where it says: "A triangle is the set of points

[image]

where for some point po, where u and v range over the parametric coordinates (we are talking about barycentric coordinates here) of the triangle"

I don't understand this statement. How come that each point in a triangle surface can be expressed as the expression above?

Answer (score 2):

Figured out: p0 is a point inside the triangle, u and v are the barycentric coordinates that are "weights" to use dp/du and dp/dv that represent how much does the surface vary in both directions (they're vectors since p is the barycentric equation for the triangle). u and v are b1 and b2 since b0 = 1 - b1 - b2 (barycentric coords sum to 1)

Comment: You're obviously referring to the PBR-book. I've also got trouble to understand what the authors mean. What's confusing me is that shouldn't we simply have $p(u,v)=p_0+ue_1+ve_2$, where $e_i:=p_i-p_0$?